# Unable to open secure websocket connections in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket

Following is my asgi, which worked perfectly fine for normal websocket connection ws:// But it fails when the frontend tries to open secure websocket connection via wss://  Kindly let me know what needs to be done.

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": URLRouter([path('ws/notifications/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi())]),
    }
)
```

Channel setup

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {"hosts": [("redis", 6379)], "prefix": "siml:"},
    },
}
```

Comment: You should let a proxy server (for example nginx) or your ASGI server (for example uvicorn) handle everything TLS related. Your Django app should remain as-is

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use Daphne.  If I shouldn't be doing it, kindly let me know.